# ssh has stopped working on WLAN

Tags: networking, ssh

I have two machines on the same wireless LAN. I can ssh from machineA to machineB but not the other way around. The error is:

```
fred@ms-Precision-5510:~$ ssh 192.168.1.245
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.245 (192.168.1.245)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 51:29:ce:63:64:31:4c:d2:de:d1:fe:12:a6:76:08:33.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.245' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fred@ms-Precision-5510:~$
```

(The above is from a new test user account 'fred' I created just to be sure the issue wasn't specific to my own account. 192.168.1.245 is machineA. The 'fred' user can ssh from machineA to machineB.)

/etc/ssh/ssh_config is identical between the two machines. I have tried removing ~/.ssh on both machines without success. I have also tried running with -o "PreferredAuthentications password" on the command line with ssh, again without success. I have tried rebooting. It's always the same error: Permission denied (publickey).

Note that I can ping either machine from the other.

The only real clue I have here is that 1) this worked last week and 2) invoking ssh with -vvv yields the following towards the end of the debug transcript:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/ms/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ms/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ms/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ms/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ms/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ms/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or         directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ms/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ms/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or   directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ms/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ms/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ms/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/ms/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Note the "Authentications that can continue" line. When I (successfully) ssh from machineA to machineB, that line is:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

So, apparently I've somehow told machineA not to accept authentication via password. I can't find where this might have been done, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is the configuration file for the `ssh` client, not the server. Is there a line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (note the `d`) that says `PasswordAuthentication no`?

Comment: Yep, that was it. Everything working fine now. Thanks!